# Connecting to Repl from Clojure project Light Table

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop, lighttable

I am trying to connect to Repl in Clojure project in Light Table. I went to connections, chose project.clj I wanted to connect to but unfortunately without success. I created project with "lein new app my-app". Before this, I had tried to connect with some another project that I had created with Luminus template and it was successfully. But when I made this simple app with "lein new app my-app" I cant connect. I got the following error:

```
We couldn't connect.

Looks like there was an issue trying to connect to the project. Here's what we got:
final project:  {:description FIXME: write description, :compile-path C:\Users\nenad\Desktop\my-first-neural-network\target\base+system+user+dev+8ddc75d4\classes, :deploy-repositories [[clojars {:url https://clojars.org/repo/, :password :gpg, :username :gpg}]], :group my-first-neural-network, :license {:name EPL-2.0 OR GPL-2.0-or-later WITH Classpath-exception-2.0, :url https://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-2.0/}, :java-cmd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin\java.exe, :resource-paths (C:\Users\nenad\Desktop\my-first-neural-network\dev-resources C:\Users\nenad\Desktop\my-first-neural-network\resources), :uberjar-merge-with {META-INF/plexus/components.xml leiningen.uberjar/components-merger, data_readers.clj leiningen.uberjar/clj-map-merger, #"META-INF/services/.*" [clojure.core/slurp (fn* [p1__953__955__auto__ p2__954__956__auto__] (clojure.core/str p1__953__955__auto__ 
 p2__954__956__auto__)) clojure.core/spit]}, :name my-first-neural-network, :checkout-deps-shares [:source-paths :test-paths :resource-paths :compile-path #'leiningen.core.classpath/checkout-deps-paths], :source-paths (C:\Users\nenad\Desktop\my-first-neural-network\src), :eval-in :subprocess, :repositories [[central {:url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/, :snapshots false}] [clojars {:url https://clojars.org/repo/}]], :test-paths (C:\Users\nenad\Desktop\my-first-neural-network\test), :target-path C:\Users\nenad\Desktop\my-first-neural-network\target\base+system+user+dev+8ddc75d4, :prep-tasks [javac compile], :native-path C:\Users\nenad\Desktop\my-first-neural-network\target\base+system+user+dev+8ddc75d4\native, :offline? false, :root C:\Users\nenad\Desktop\my-first-neural-network, :pedantic? ranges, :clean-targets [:target-path], :plugins [], :url http://example.com/FIXME, :profiles {:uberjar {:aot [:all], :jvm-opts nil, :eval-in nil}}, :plugin-repositories [[central {:url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/, :snapshots false}] [clojars {:url https://clojars.org/repo/}]], :version 0.1.0-SNAPSHOT, :jar-exclusions [#"^\."], :main my-first-neural-network.core, :global-vars {}, :uberjar-exclusions [#"(?i)^META-INF/[^/]*\.(SF|RSA|DSA)$"], :jvm-opts [], :dependencies ([org.clojure/clojure 1.10.0] [org.clojure/tools.nrepl 0.2.10 :exclusions ([org.clojure/clojure])] [clojure-complete/clojure-complete 0.2.3 :exclusions ([org.clojure/clojure])] [lein-light-nrepl/lein-light-nrepl 0.3.3] [lein-light-nrepl-instarepl/lein-light-nrepl-instarepl 0.3.1]), :release-tasks [[vcs assert-committed] [change version leiningen.release/bump-version release] [vcs commit] [vcs tag] [deploy] [change version leiningen.release/bump-version] [vcs commit] [vcs push]], :repl-options {:nrepl-middleware [lighttable.nrepl.handler/lighttable-ops], :init (clojure.core/swap! lighttable.nrepl.core/my-settings clojure.core/merge {:name my-first-neural-network 0.1.0-SNAPSHOT, :project (quote {:description FIXME: write description, :compile-path C:\Users\nenad\Desktop\my-first-neural-network\target\base+system+user+dev\classes, :deploy-repositories [[clojars {:url https://clojars.org/repo/, :password :gpg, :username :gpg}]], :group my-first-neural-network, :license {:name EPL-2.0 OR GPL-2.0-or-later WITH Classpath-exception-2.0, :url https://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-2.0/}, :java-cmd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin\java.exe, :resource-paths (C:\Users\nenad\Desktop\my-first-neural-network\dev-resources C:\Users\nenad\Desktop\my-first-neural-network\resources), :uberjar-merge-with {META-INF/plexus/components.xml leiningen.uberjar/components-merger, data_readers.clj leiningen.uberjar/clj-map-merger, #"META-INF/services/.*" [clojure.core/slurp (fn* [p1__953__955__auto__ p2__954__956__auto__] (clojure.core/str p1__953__955__auto__ 
 p2__954__956__auto__)) clojure.core/spit]}, :name my-first-neural-network, :checkout-deps-shares [:source-paths :test-paths :resource-paths :compile-path #'leiningen.core.classpath/checkout-deps-paths], :source-paths (C:\Users\nenad\Desktop\my-first-neural-network\src), :eval-in :subprocess, :repositories [[central {:url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/, :snapshots false}] [clojars {:url https://clojars.org/repo/}]], :test-paths (C:\Users\nenad\Desktop\my-first-neural-network\test), :target-path C:\Users\nenad\Desktop\my-first-neural-network\target\base+system+user+dev, :prep-tasks [javac compile], :native-path C:\Users\nenad\Desktop\my-first-neural-network\target\base+system+user+dev\native, :offline? false, :root C:\Users\nenad\Desktop\my-first-neural-network, :pedantic? ranges, :clean-targets [:target-path], :plugins [], :url http://example.com/FIXME, :profiles {:uberjar {:aot [:all], :jvm-opts nil, :eval-in nil}}, :plugin-repositories [[central {:url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/, :snapshots false}] [clojars {:url https://clojars.org/repo/}]], :version 0.1.0-SNAPSHOT, :jar-exclusions [#"^\."], :main my-first-neural-network.core, :global-vars {}, :uberjar-exclusions [#"(?i)^META-INF/[^/]*\.(SF|RSA|DSA)$"], :jvm-opts [], :dependencies ([org.clojure/clojure 1.10.0] [org.clojure/tools.nrepl 0.2.10 :exclusions ([org.clojure/clojure])] [clojure-complete/clojure-complete 0.2.3 :exclusions ([org.clojure/clojure])]), :release-tasks [[vcs assert-committed] [change version leiningen.release/bump-version release] [vcs commit] [vcs tag] [deploy] [change version leiningen.release/bump-version] [vcs commit] [vcs push]], :test-selectors {:default (constantly true)}})})}, :test-selectors {:default (constantly true)}}
Error loading lighttable.nrepl.handler: Syntax error macroexpanding clojure.core/ns at (cljs/source_map/base64_vlq.clj:1:1).
Exception in thread "main" Syntax error compiling var at (C:\Users\nenad\AppData\Local\Temp\form-init2299474071958135132.clj:1:5184).
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:7114)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6789)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6745)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3888)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:7108)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6789)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6745)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3888)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:7108)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6789)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.access$300(Compiler.java:38)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$LetExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:6384)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:7106)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6789)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6745)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:6120)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$FnMethod.parse(Compiler.java:5467)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$FnExpr.parse(Compiler.java:4029)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:7104)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6789)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:7173)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:7166)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7635)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7573)
    at clojure.main$load_script.invokeStatic(main.clj:452)
    at clojure.main$init_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:454)
    at clojure.main$init_opt.invoke(main.clj:454)
    at clojure.main$initialize.invokeStatic(main.clj:485)
    at clojure.main$null_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:519)
    at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:516)
    at clojure.main$main.invokeStatic(main.clj:598)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:561)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:705)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve var: lighttable.nrepl.handler/lighttable-ops in this context
    at clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException(Util.java:221)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$TheVarExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:720)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:7106)
    ... 34 more
clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: Subprocess failed {:exit-code 1}
    at clojure.core$ex_info.invoke(core.clj:4593)
    at leiningen.core.eval$fn__2432.invoke(eval.clj:236)
    at clojure.lang.MultiFn.invoke(MultiFn.java:233)
    at leiningen.core.eval$eval_in_project.invoke(eval.clj:337)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:160)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:632)
    at leiningen.repl$repl.doInvoke(repl.clj:322)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:425)
    at leiningen.light_nrepl$light.invoke(light_nrepl.clj:77)
    at leiningen.light_nrepl$_main.doInvoke(light_nrepl.clj:85)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:397)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:152)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:132)
    at leiningen.light_nrepl.main(Unknown Source)

close
```

I changed Clojure version in project.clj file in root of the project but now I cant start REPL. I got the follwing error:

```
Starting nREPL server...
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin\java.exe" -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 -Dconf=dev-config.edn -Dclojure.compile.path=C:\Users\nenad\Desktop\Vezba\myapp\target\default\classes -Dmyapp.version=0.1.0-SNAPSHOT -Dclojure.debug=false "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.3.5\lib\idea_rt.jar=49713:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.3.5\bin" -classpath C:\Users\nenad\Desktop\Vezba\myapp\test\clj;C:\Users\nenad\Desktop\Vezba\myapp\env\dev\clj;C:\Users\nenad\Desktop\Vezba\myapp\src\clj;C:\Users\nenad\Desktop\Vezba\myapp\env\dev\resources;C:\Users\nenad\Desktop\Vezba\myapp\dev-resources;C:\Users\nenad\Desktop\Vezba\myapp\resources;C:\Users\nenad\Desktop\Vezba\myapp\target\default\classes;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\metosin\reitit-core\0.3.1\reitit-core-0.3.1.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\ring\ring-core\1.7.1\ring-core-1.7.1.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\funcool\cuerdas\2.0.5\cuerdas-2.0.5.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\clojure-complete\clojure-complete\0.2.5\clojure-complete-0.2.5.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\org\clojure\clojure\1.8.0\clojure-1.8.0.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\cprop\cprop\0.1.13\cprop-0.1.13.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\org\msgpack\msgpack\0.6.12\msgpack-0.6.12.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\org\webjars\webjars-locator\0.36\webjars-locator-0.36.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\expound\expound\0.7.2\expound-0.7.2.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\lambdaisland\deep-diff\0.0-25\deep-diff-0.0-25.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\tigris\tigris\0.1.1\tigris-0.1.1.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\mvxcvi\arrangement\1.1.1\arrangement-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\org\projectodd\wunderboss\wunderboss-web\0.13.1\wunderboss-web-0.13.1.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\metosin\reitit-dev\0.3.1\reitit-dev-0.3.1.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.1.3\logback-classic-1.1.3.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\metosin\reitit-swagger\0.3.1\reitit-swagger-0.3.1.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\selmer\selmer\1.12.12\selmer-1.12.12.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\metosin\reitit-schema\0.3.1\reitit-schema-0.3.1.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\com\cognitect\transit-clj\0.8.313\transit-clj-0.8.313.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\org\projectodd\wunderboss\wunderboss-core\0.13.1\wunderboss-core-0.13.1.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\org\clojure\core.rrb-vector\0.0.13\core.rrb-vector-0.0.13.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\meta-merge\meta-merge\1.0.0\meta-merge-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\joda-time\joda-time\2.9.9\joda-time-2.9.9.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\ring\ring-headers\0.3.0\ring-headers-0.3.0.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\pjstadig\humane-test-output\0.9.0\humane-test-output-0.9.0.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\javax\xml\bind\jaxb-api\2.3.0\jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.8.1\commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\mount\mount\0.1.16\mount-0.1.16.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\ring\ring-ssl\0.3.0\ring-ssl-0.3.0.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.9.7\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.7.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\org\projectodd\wunderboss\wunderboss-web-undertow\0.13.1\wunderboss-web-undertow-0.13.1.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\metosin\reitit\0.3.1\reitit-0.3.1.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\metosin\reitit-spec\0.3.1\reitit-spec-0.3.1.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\commons-fileupload\commons-fileupload\1.3.3\commons-fileupload-1.3.3.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\io\undertow\undertow-core\1.4.14.Final\undertow-core-1.4.14.Final.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\metosin\reitit-middleware\0.3.1\reitit-middleware-0.3.1.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\prone\prone\1.6.1\prone-1.6.1.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\metosin\jsonista\0.2.2\jsonista-0.2.2.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\servlet\jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec\1.0.0.Final\jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\net\jodah\expiringmap\0.5.8\expiringmap-0.5.8.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\org\immutant\web\2.1.10\web-2.1.10.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\ring\ring-mock\0.3.2\ring-mock-0.3.2.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\prismatic\schema\1.1.9\schema-1.1.9.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\metosin\spec-tools\0.9.0\spec-tools-0.9.0.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\org\webjars\npm\material-icons\0.3.0\material-icons-0.3.0.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\org\clojure\tools.reader\0.10.0\tools.reader-0.10.0.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\org\ow2\asm\asm\5.1\asm-5.1.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\ring\ring-codec\1.1.1\ring-codec-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\nrepl\nrepl\0.6.0\nrepl-0.6.0.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\websocket\jboss-websocket-api_1.1_spec\1.1.0.Final\jboss-websocket-api_1.1_spec-1.1.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\io\undertow\undertow-websockets-jsr\1.4.14.Final\undertow-websockets-jsr-1.4.14.Final.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\ns-tracker\ns-tracker\0.3.1\ns-tracker-0.3.1.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\org\clojure\java.classpath\0.2.3\java.classpath-0.2.3.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\org\webjars\webjars-locator-jboss-vfs\0.1.0\webjars-locator-jboss-vfs-0.1.0.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\2.6\commons-io-2.6.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\metosin\reitit-ring\0.3.1\reitit-ring-0.3.1.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\crypto-equality\crypto-equality\1.0.0\crypto-equality-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\tech\droit\clj-diff\1.0.0\clj-diff-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\org\jboss\xnio\xnio-api\3.3.6.Final\xnio-api-3.3.6.Final.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\org\projectodd\wunderboss\wunderboss-clojure\0.13.1\wunderboss-clojure-0.13.1.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\luminus-transit\luminus-transit\0.1.1\luminus-transit-0.1.1.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\org\jboss\xnio\xnio-nio\3.3.6.Final\xnio-nio-3.3.6.Final.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\metosin\reitit-sieppari\0.3.1\reitit-sieppari-0.3.1.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\com\cognitect\transit-js\0.8.846\transit-js-0.8.846.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\org\webjars\npm\bulma\0.7.4\bulma-0.7.4.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\metosin\ring-swagger-ui\2.2.10\ring-swagger-ui-2.2.10.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.11\commons-codec-1.11.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\com\googlecode\json-simple\json-simple\1.1.1\json-simple-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\hiccup\hiccup\1.0.5\hiccup-1.0.5.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\org\webjars\webjars-locator-core\0.37\webjars-locator-core-0.37.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\clj-tuple\clj-tuple\0.2.2\clj-tuple-0.2.2.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\mvxcvi\puget\1.0.3\puget-1.0.3.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\clj-time\clj-time\0.14.3\clj-time-0.14.3.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\json-html\json-html\0.4.4\json-html-0.4.4.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\org\clojure\tools.logging\0.4.1\tools.logging-0.4.1.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\metosin\reitit-swagger-ui\0.3.1\reitit-swagger-ui-0.3.1.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\annotation\jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec\1.0.0.Final\jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\ring\ring-devel\1.7.1\ring-devel-1.7.1.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\luminus-immutant\luminus-immutant\0.2.5\luminus-immutant-0.2.5.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\org\clojure\tools.cli\0.4.2\tools.cli-0.4.2.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\org\clojure\tools.namespace\0.2.11\tools.namespace-0.2.11.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\metosin\ring-http-response\0.9.1\ring-http-response-0.9.1.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\potemkin\potemkin\0.4.5\potemkin-0.4.5.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\expiring-map\expiring-map\0.1.8\expiring-map-0.1.8.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\com\cognitect\transit-java\0.8.337\transit-java-0.8.337.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\metosin\reitit-interceptors\0.3.1\reitit-interceptors-0.3.1.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.7\slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\virgil\virgil\0.1.6\virgil-0.1.6.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\metosin\schema-tools\0.11.0\schema-tools-0.11.0.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\ring-webjars\ring-webjars\0.2.0\ring-webjars-0.2.0.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\luminus\ring-ttl-session\0.3.2\ring-ttl-session-0.3.2.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\metosin\muuntaja\0.6.4\muuntaja-0.6.4.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\crypto-random\crypto-random\1.2.0\crypto-random-1.2.0.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\javax.servlet-api\3.1.0\javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\riddley\riddley\0.1.12\riddley-0.1.12.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.9.8\jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\metosin\sieppari\0.0.0-alpha7\sieppari-0.0.0-alpha7.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\com\cognitect\transit-cljs\0.8.256\transit-cljs-0.8.256.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\fipp\fipp\0.6.17\fipp-0.6.17.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\markdown-clj\markdown-clj\1.0.7\markdown-clj-1.0.7.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\org\immutant\core\2.1.10\core-2.1.10.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\cheshire\cheshire\5.8.1\cheshire-5.8.1.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\io\undertow\undertow-servlet\1.4.14.Final\undertow-servlet-1.4.14.Final.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.9.6\jackson-core-2.9.6.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\dataformat\jackson-dataformat-cbor\2.9.6\jackson-dataformat-cbor-2.9.6.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.9.0\jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\metosin\reitit-frontend\0.3.1\reitit-frontend-0.3.1.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.1.3\logback-core-1.1.3.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\com\andrewmcveigh\cljs-time\0.5.2\cljs-time-0.5.2.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.2.1.Final\jboss-logging-3.2.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\ring\ring-anti-forgery\1.3.0\ring-anti-forgery-1.3.0.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\realize\realize\1.1.0\realize-1.1.0.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-compress\1.18\commons-compress-1.18.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.18.1-GA\javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\funcool\struct\1.3.0\struct-1.3.0.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\metosin\reitit-http\0.3.1\reitit-http-0.3.1.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\clojure\java-time\clojure.java-time\0.3.2\clojure.java-time-0.3.2.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\ring\ring-defaults\0.3.2\ring-defaults-0.3.2.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\org\clojure\spec.alpha\0.2.176\spec.alpha-0.2.176.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\dataformat\jackson-dataformat-smile\2.9.6\jackson-dataformat-smile-2.9.6.jar;C:\Users\nenad\.m2\repository\clj-stacktrace\clj-stacktrace\0.2.8\clj-stacktrace-0.2.8.jar clojure.main -i C:\Users\nenad\AppData\Local\Temp\form-init47301827214867056.clj
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at clojure.main.<clinit>(main.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError, compiling:(user.clj:1:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7391)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:372)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:359)
    at clojure.lang.RT.maybeLoadResourceScript(RT.java:355)
    at clojure.lang.RT.doInit(RT.java:475)
    at clojure.lang.RT.<clinit>(RT.java:331)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2168)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2177)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2196)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:443)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:419)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5677.invoke(core.clj:5893)
    at clojure.core$load.invokeStatic(core.clj:5892)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5876)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invokeStatic(core.clj:5697)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5692)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5626.invoke(core.clj:5737)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.invokeStatic(core.clj:5736)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5717)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:648)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.invokeStatic(core.clj:5774)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5758)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:648)
    at clojure.core$require.invokeStatic(core.clj:5796)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5796)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:482)
    at user$eval3$loading__5569__auto____4.invoke(user.clj:1)
    at user$eval3.invokeStatic(user.clj:1)
    at user$eval3.invoke(user.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6927)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6916)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7379)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempting to call unbound fn: #'clojure.core/ident?
    at clojure.lang.Var$Unbound.throwArity(Var.java:43)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.invoke(AFn.java:32)
    at clojure.spec.alpha$spec_impl.invokeStatic(alpha.clj:915)
    at clojure.spec.alpha$spec_impl.invoke(alpha.clj:908)
    at clojure.spec.alpha__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at clojure.spec.alpha__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    ... 37 more
Exception in thread "main" 
Process finished with exit code 1
Exception starting REPL: java.lang.InterruptedException
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connect to Repl from Light Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55642475/connect-to-repl-from-light-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm. The problem here is, LT doesn't support a Clojure project running Clojure >1.8.0. Yes, LT needs to update to support new Clojure/Script versions. There are WIP patches to help make this possible. For now, sadly, you'll have to drop down to older releases of Clojure.

Comment: I changed Clojure version in my project.clj of particular project but now I cant start lein repl. I got the following errro:

Comment: The best way to solve this problem RN is by using jdk8. But, other solutions too are available around of adding certain packages. There had been some discussions here: [Trouble with jre 9](https://github.com/LightTable/LightTable/issues/2358)